# Помогите определить синтаксическую функцию

Tags: синтаксис

Скажите, пожалуйста, чем являются глаголы *считаешь*, *захочет*, *хочешь* с синтаксической точки зрения?

(1) *Расспроси его о чем **считаешь** необходимым.*

(2) *Можете стрелять кто когда **захочет**.*

(3) *Делай с этим письмом что **хочешь**.*

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

(1) Расспроси его о чем считаешь необходимым.-Определённо-личное односоставное предложение.Расспроси (о чём?) о чём считаешь необходимым - дополнение, выраженное фразеологизмом = "о необходимом".

(2) Можете стрелять кто когда захочет.-Определённо-личное предложение.Стрелять (когда?)кто когда захочет-обстоятельство, выраженное фразеологизмом = "всегда"= "по желанию".

(3)  Делай с этим письмом что хочешь.Делай (что?)что хочешь-фразеологизм, являющийся  дополнением, заменяет слово "ВСЁ".Но иногда такой тип фразеологизмов разбирают как сказуемое(Что делай с этим письмом?)Делай что хочешь. Смотрите, как разбирают в Вашем учебном заведении.

Comment: Hmm, видимо в наших языках большая разница между понятиями "фразеологизм". У нас к таким относят сочетания tipo "быть бедным как мерлуза" или "черная овечка"... Неужели на самом деле в русском языке "о чём считаешь необходимым" принимают за фразеологизм?!

Comment: Фразеологизм здесь не пословица или поговорка, а слитное выражение, которое заменяет одно слово и является одним членом предложения, например: бросил взгляд=посмотрел

Comment: нет нет, я не имела в виду только поговорки и пословицы. это у нас  могут быть сросшиеся синтагмы и смысл слов понимается в их единстве (извините, мне трудно сформулировать определение красиво). Поэтому мне показалось странным что "о чём считаешь необходимым" считают фразеологизмом, так как на мои взгляд можно понять компоненты по отдельности. Но я полагаюсь на Ваши ответы, так как сама мало знаю : )

Answer (score 0):

Глаголы "считаешь, захочет, хочешь" входят в цельные по смыслу выражения, обычно  имеющие значение одного слова. **У глаголов нет самостоятельной синтаксической функции,** но сами цельные выражения могут быть в предложении дополнением, обстоятельством или другим членом.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что в данных предложениях все выделенные глаголы - это сказуемые.      (1) Расспроси его о чем СЧИТАЕШЬ необходимым.(2) Можете стрелять кто когда ЗАХОЧЕТ.(3) Делай с этим письмом что ХОЧЕШЬ.
В (1) пропущено сочетание указательного местоимения и относительного местоимения О ТОМ, О ЧЁМ.  Расспроси его о том, о чём СЧИТАЕШЬ необходимым.
Во (2) пропущено наречие ТОГДА. Иначе получится речевая ошибка и неблагозвучное нагромождение согласных (ТОГДА КТО КОГДА).Можете стрелять тогда, кто когда ЗАХОЧЕТ.
В (3)пропущено указательное местоимение ТО. Делай с этим письмом то,что ХОЧЕШЬ.
Таким образом, каждое из трёх СПП трансформировалось в простое предложение.